# How can I discover the file descriptor associated with the python turtle or turtle screen?

Tags: python, sockets, python-multithreading, turtle-graphics

I have students writing an application that uses sockets with multiple clients, doing two way communications with the server and each other. It roughly started out with this code:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/simple-chat-room-using-python/

Unfortunately I do not have the exact code, but can describe what we are doing, and what the problem is.

Each client program instance (as opposed to the client thread proxy method on the server) also instantiates a turtle for graphics (TkInter), and we want to communicate the state of the graphics back to the server. The problem arrises because in order to get a turtle screen to stay on the display, we have to use the mainloop() method which is blocking. But our chat thing is also executing a run loop on the client.

We extracted the client program run loop code into its own method, and fired that off on it's own thread before creating the turtle and it's drawing. Our turtle (which we encapsulated in it's own separate class/file) want's to process mouse clicks. With some finagling we got all the threads to play together and have our client program run loops and the turtle mainloops with the click-catchers all working.

The environment is Ubuntu Linux, and Python 3.

Best I can do for a listing at the moment is:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/simple-chat-room-using-python/

The clients are able to connect, and broadcast and send messages. As soon as we click on the turtle screen, the client run loop goes haywire and we are having a hard time discerning what becomes of the signal. We've tracked the disappearance to the select.select which I'm having a little difficulty figuring out how it works. As soon as you click the turtle screen, the turtle click-catcher fires off and processes the click, however the code in the client program run loop is also trying to process the mouse click in the select.select mechanism. It doesn't throw an exception, but it doesn't return either. We bracketed the select.select with print statements to try and debug, but the code doesn't execute on the line following select.select after the mouse click. If we click again, the run loop will again do the print before the select.select, but the thread of execution seems to disappear again. ??

I figure if we could discover what the file descriptor is for the turtle screen, we might be able to stop it from getting clogged up in the select.select. We looked at the turtle screen's '''python__dict__''', but didn't have any luck finding an fd.